# How can I make a class duration to store time length?

Tags: c++, operators

I am trying to write a class with 3 attribute and some constructors and following methods:  `set (h, m, s)`, `Double getHousrs ()` operator +
`correctTime()`. To change e.g 1:76:84 to 2:13:13

**Current code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class duration {
 public:
  duration(int h, int m, int s)
  :hour (h), minutes (m), seconds (s);
  {}
  void printDate()
  {
   cout << hour<< ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds << endl;
  }
  double getHours() {
        return hours;
    }
    double getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }
 private:
  int hour;
  int minutes;
  int seconds;
  duration operator+(duration &obj)
  { }
};

int main()
{
    duration obj;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"I coudn't enter my code here!!"_ No excuses: 1st section in the [editor help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). If it's too much code, add more explanation or narrow it down to a [MCVE].

Comment: @JJcopl Don't insult other members.

Comment: sorry about that, I didn't want to be rude but some people here just make a very clever figure of themselves and just complaining and giving some negative mark. instead of help. of course, I tried to do my best.

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: Why don't you just use [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)?

Comment: @JJcopl _"instead of help"_ 1. I well tried to help you. 2. The site isn't meant as your _personal helpdesk_ but to build up a useful FAQ like repository for future research. Make sure a new question you ask here fits these requirements.

Comment: #Jake Freeman, to be honest, no, maybe I don't know how to put it in my code. you can check updated code here: https://code.sololearn.com/cXk3ro7tNznM/#cpp

Comment: @JesperJuhl how should I use that for my purpose?

Comment: @JJcopl _"how should I use that for my purpose?"_ As described in the examples [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). Please mind to do some research before asking.

Comment: @JJcopl I updated my answer it now fixes all the errors in your class and some in my orginal operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem would be to add the values together which can be most efficiently done like this I also fixed all the other errors you had in your class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class duration {
 public:
  duration(int h, int m, int s)
  :hour (h), minute (m), second (s)
  {}
  void printDate()
  {
   cout << hour<< ":" << minute << ":" << second << endl;
  }
  double getHours() {
        return hour;
    }
    double getSeconds() {
        return second;
    }
  duration operator + (const duration& other)
    {

    duration temp(0, 0, 0);
    temp.second = (other.second+second)%60;
    temp.minute = ((other.second + second)/60 + other.minute + minute)%60;
    temp.hour = ((other.minute+minute)/60 + other.hour + hour)%60;
    return temp;

    }   
 private:
  int hour;
  int minute;
  int second;

};

int main()
{
    duration obj(3, 5, 10);
    duration obj2(4, 55, 40);

    duration temp = obj + obj2;

    temp.printDate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JJcopl could you please upvote and accept if it works.

Comment: yes it works, thank you. I tried to upvote but unfortunetally I can't. I get a message that says, I can't upvote because I have less than 15 reputation or sth like that. but I made it best answer